# Is there a really simple method for printing scraped output to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

*Python: Python 3.11.2
Python Editor: PyCharm 2022.3.3 (Community Edition) - Build PC-223.8836.43
OS: Windows 11 Pro, 22H2, 22621.1413
Browser: Chrome 111.0.5563.65 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

I have a URL (e.g., `https://dockets.justia.com/docket/puerto-rico/prdce/3:2023cv01127/175963`) from which I'm scraping nine items. I'm looking to have the script create a csv file and write my scraped output (nine items) to columns in the csv file.  Is there a really simple way of doing this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

html_text = requests.get("https://dockets.justia.com/docket/puerto-rico/prdce/3:2023cv01127/175963").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
cases = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "wrapper jcard has-padding-30 blocks has-no-bottom-padding")

for case in cases:
    case_title = case.find("div", class_ = "title-wrapper").text.replace(" "," ")
    case_plaintiff = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Plaintiff"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    case_defendant = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Defendant"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    case_number = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Case Number"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    case_filed = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Filed"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    court = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Court"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    case_nature_of_suit = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Nature of Suit"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    case_cause_of_action = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Cause of Action"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    jury_demanded = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Jury Demanded By"}).text.replace(" "," ")

    print(f"{case_title.strip()}")
    print(f"{case_plaintiff.strip()}")
    print(f"{case_defendant.strip()}")
    print(f"{case_number.strip()}")
    print(f"{case_filed.strip()}")
    print(f"{court.strip()}")
    print(f"{case_nature_of_suit.strip()}")
    print(f"{case_cause_of_action.strip()}")
    print(f"{jury_demanded.strip()}")
```

Comment: There are many tutorials and examples on the web that explain how to create a csv file using python.  I'm not sure what your actual question is.

Comment: @JohnGordon Your "write those nine values to it" approach completely ignores e.g. escaping commas within a single field.

Comment: @AKX I'm aware.  Overly simplistic solutions are a way to get the questioner to provide more detail about what they _really_ need.

Comment: @John Gordon Sorry, I should have emphasized my neophyte-ness. I basically need the items in the printed output - which in the script I provided basically just prints the scraped data to the console in rows - distributed across columns in a csv file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`pandas` has a [`.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method.

```py
# import pandas as pd
csv_filename = 'x.csv' #<--name or path to file

th_fields = ['Plaintiff', 'Defendant', 'Case Number', 'Filed', 'Court', 
             'Nature of Suit', 'Cause of Action', 'Jury Demanded By']
case_rows = []
for c in cases:
    title = c.find("div", class_ = "title-wrapper")
    row = {'title': title.text.strip()} if title else {}
    for td in c.find_all('td',{'data-th':(lambda th: th in th_fields)}): 
        row[td['data-th']] = td.text.strip()
    case_rows.append(row)

pd.DataFrame(case_rows).to_csv(csv_filename, index=False)
# pd.DataFrame(case_rows).T.to_csv(csv_filename, index=False, header=False)
```

[image: op1]

You can also [transpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp6Zd.png) it with [`.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html).

[image: op1.5]

---

You can also get all the tables from the URL directly with [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

```py
# import pandas as pd
url=f'https://dockets.justia.com/docket/puerto-rico/prdce/3:2023cv01127/175963'
csv_filename = 'x.csv'
for ti, df in enumerate(pd.read_html(url)):
    df.to_csv(csv_filename, mode='a' if ti else 'w', index=False)
    pd.DataFrame({'':[]}).to_csv(csv_filename, mode='a')
```

[image: op2]

Comment: That last script sure is simple and effective but includes too much extraneous information. Also the row contents should be columns (even as that would create a hell of a lot of columns for for cases with 3-4000 docket entries.

Comment: It's simple *because* it just grabs all the tables without any filtering or extra processing; however, you can transpose with `df.T` you can limit the number of rows (which will become transposed to columns) with `.loc` (eg.: [**like this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0IXu.png) -  *`.loc[:4 if ti else len(df)]`* limits it to 4+1 entries, and it's conditional so that everything from the first table remains)

Comment: Love the simplicity! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Generate a list of lists with your data and dump that out to a csv:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

html_text = requests.get("https://dockets.justia.com/docket/puerto-rico/prdce/3:2023cv01127/175963").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
cases = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "wrapper jcard has-padding-30 blocks has-no-bottom-padding")

output = []
for case in cases:
    case_title = case.find("div", class_ = "title-wrapper").text.replace(" "," ")
    case_plaintiff = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Plaintiff"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    case_defendant = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Defendant"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    case_number = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Case Number"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    case_filed = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Filed"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    court = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Court"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    case_nature_of_suit = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Nature of Suit"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    case_cause_of_action = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Cause of Action"}).text.replace(" "," ")
    jury_demanded = case.find("td", {"data-th": "Jury Demanded By"}).text.replace(" "," ")

    output.append([
                    case_title.strip()
                    ,case_plaintiff.strip()
                    ,case_defendant.strip()
                    ,case_number.strip()
                    ,case_filed.strip()
                    ,court.strip()
                    ,case_nature_of_suit.strip()
                    ,case_cause_of_action.strip()
                    ,jury_demanded.strip()
                  ])


with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(output)
```

Comment: Oops, I'm getting the following message - need to figure out what that means ;-) : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cs\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\beautsoup.py", line 36, in <module>
    writer.writerows("output")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: `writer.writerows(output)` instead. We don't want to write the word `"output"` to the file, we want to write the list-of-lists object stored in variable `output` to the file.

Comment: Not sure exactly what that means. But I changed the line
with open("output.csv", "bw") as f:  to
with open("output.csv", "w") as f:

and it works! I just hope that I've not committed an act that will cause the Pythonverse to melt down in doing that. Thanks so much to both you and AKX for your help!

Comment: *"Not sure exactly what that means."*: I was pointing out the diffferent in `writer.writerows("output")` and `write.writerows(output)`. You used the former, and it errored. I used the latter in my answer, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sure – the easiest is the standard library `csv` module.

I took the liberty of refactoring your `.replace().strip()` stuff with a single function; we're also gathering up all of the case data into a list-of-dicts first before writing it out to a file. This makes it easier to add new columns without having to deal with their names twice.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv


def process_text(s):
    return s.replace(" ", " ").strip()


html_text = requests.get("https://dockets.justia.com/docket/puerto-rico/prdce/3:2023cv01127/175963").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
cases = soup.find_all("div", class_="wrapper jcard has-padding-30 blocks has-no-bottom-padding")

data = []

for case in cases:
    data.append(
        {
            "case_title": process_text(case.find("div", class_="title-wrapper")),
            "case_plaintiff": process_text(case.find("td", {"data-th": "Plaintiff"})),
            "case_defendant": process_text(case.find("td", {"data-th": "Defendant"})),
            "case_number": process_text(case.find("td", {"data-th": "Case Number"})),
            "case_filed": process_text(case.find("td", {"data-th": "Filed"})),
            "court": process_text(case.find("td", {"data-th": "Court"})),
            "case_nature_of_suit": process_text(case.find("td", {"data-th": "Nature of Suit"})),
            "case_cause_of_action": process_text(case.find("td", {"data-th": "Cause of Action"})),
            "jury_demanded": process_text(case.find("td", {"data-th": "Jury Demanded By"})),
        }
    )

with open("cases.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=data[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Again, I apologize for being new to this - and have to spend much more time researching error codes etc. than a normal Python user (but also don't want to leave you hanging and appear ungrateful). For this, I get the error; 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 19, in <module>
    "case_title": process_text(case.find("div", class_="title-wrapper")),
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   line 7, in process_text
    return s.replace(" ", " ").strip()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: That means the thing you're passing to the function is `None` - do all cases have a title?

Comment: Yes, they all do.